# Issue with ForEach-Object loop

Tags: powershell, csv

I am having an issue with the `ForEach-Object` property running through the same server session multiple times. However, the server session on the list is only ran through once. I reckon that this is an issue with the loop.

```
if (Test-Path 'H:\demo\session\run11.csv') {
    Clear-Content 'H:\demo\session\run11.csv'
}

$Servers = Get-Content 'H:\demo\computernames.txt'
$openservers = @()

foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    if (-not (Test-Connection $Server -Count 1 -Quiet)) { continue }

    if (-not (Convert-QueryToObjects $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        $openservers += $server
        $openservers | Out-File 'H:\demo\session\openservers.txt'
    } else {  
        Convert-QueryToObjects -Name $Server | Where-Object {
            @('Disconnected','Active') -contains $_.SessionState
        } | Export-Csv H:\demo\session\run11.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
    }
}

function Disconnect-LoggedOnUser {
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory,
            ValueFromPipeline,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName,
            Position=0
        )]
        [string[]]$ComputerName,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName
        )]
        [int[]]$Id
    )

    Begin {
        $OldEAP = $ErrorActionPreference
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
    }

    Process {
        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
            $Id | ForEach-Object {
                Write-Verbose "Attempting to disconnect session $Id on $Computer"
                try {
                    rwinsta $_ /server:$Computer
                    Write-Verbose "Session $Id on $Computer successfully disconnected"
                } catch {
                    Write-Verbose 'Error disconnecting session displaying message'
                    Write-Warning "Error on $Computer, $($_.Exception.Message)"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    End {
        $ErrorActionPreference = $OldEAP
    }
}

Import-Csv 'H:\demo\session\run11.csv' | Where-Object {
    ($_.SessionState -eq 'Disconnected') -or
    (($_.IdleTime -like "*:*") -and ($_.IdleTime -gt "00:59"))
} | ForEach-Object {
    Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -Id $_.ID -Verbose 
}
```

If I remove the `-Append` from the `Export-Csv` I no longer have the issue with the loop. However, not every object is exported to the CSV (only the last server on the list is exported). How can I get every server to be exported to the CSV, and only have it run through each of the specified sessions once?

I posted the rest of my code (including the two functions to my github gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ruslive109/98f5efe1c546fc8a30688bcf5df7786a)

here is a sample output I am getting:

```
VERBOSE: Attempting to disconnect session 24 on XXX
VERBOSE: Error disconnecting session displaying message
WARNING: Error on XX, Could not reset session ID 24, Error code 5

VERBOSE: Attempting to disconnect session 24 on XXX
VERBOSE: Error disconnecting session displaying message
WARNING: Error on XX, Could not reset session ID 24, Error code 5

VERBOSE: Attempting to disconnect session 3 on XX
VERBOSE: Error disconnecting session displaying message
WARNING: Error on XX, Could not reset session ID 3, Error code 5

VERBOSE: Attempting to disconnect session 24 on XXX
VERBOSE: Error disconnecting session displaying message
WARNING: Error on XX, Could not reset session ID 24, Error code 5

VERBOSE: Attempting to disconnect session 3 on XX
VERBOSE: Error disconnecting session displaying message
WARNING: Error on XX, Could not reset session ID 3, Error code 5


VERBOSE: Attempting to disconnect session 14 on XX
VERBOSE: Error disconnecting session displaying message
WARNING: Error on XX, Could not reset session ID 14, Error code 5
```

Comment: Looks like improperly balanced curly braces. You pipe to `Select-Object` *inside* the `Where-Object` filter scriptblock. Move the last `}` before `Export-Csv` up to just before `|Select-Object`

Comment: What are the additional sets of curly brackets in the `Where-Object` condition block for (`Where-Object { {...} | Select-Object {...} }`)?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for that, however, after playing around with it further, I realized that I actually don't even need the 'select-object' here since those values are defined earlier in the script (not shown here). However, I am still getting an issue. Please see updated question.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thank you for your input, however; I realized the select-object is irrelevant since those values are defined earlier in the script )not shown here) please see updated question.

Comment: Your `ForEach-Object` loop could only produce duplicate output if `Convert-QueryToObjects` produced duplicate input. Please check the generated CSV. Also, note that exporting the data to a CSV and re-importing it is a useless step. For production code you should remove it and merge the two `Where-Object` filters.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for that! the issue originated from the functions not being in correct order - I've rearranged and its fixed (see updated question) I am not sure how you would merge the import and export in where-object filter? can you explain further? thank you

Comment: Your updated question doesn't even have an `Export-Csv` anymore. Please do not modify questions to a point where they become incomprehensible. What I meant with my previous comment was to change the `... | Where-Object {A} | Export-Csv ...; Import-Csv ... | Where-Object {B} | ...` to `... | Where-Object {A -and B} | ...`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for taking notice, I've again updated my question, this time with the complete code. since I've re-arrange the import and export; will this suggestion still be applicable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the function definition to the beginning of your code and change

```
foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    if (-not (Test-Connection $Server -Count 1 -Quiet)) { continue }

    if (-not (Convert-QueryToObjects $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) {
        $openservers += $server
        $openservers | Out-File 'H:\demo\session\openservers.txt'
    } else {  
        Convert-QueryToObjects -Name $Server | Where-Object {
            @('Disconnected','Active') -contains $_.SessionState
        } | Export-Csv H:\demo\session\run11.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append 
    }
}

Import-Csv 'H:\demo\session\run11.csv' | Where-Object {
    ($_.SessionState -eq 'Disconnected') -or
    (($_.IdleTime -like "*:*") -and ($_.IdleTime -gt "00:59"))
} | ForEach-Object {
    Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -Id $_.ID -Verbose 
}
```

to something like

```
$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture
$reftime = [DateTime]::ParseExact('00:59', 'hh:mm', $culture)

$Servers | Where-Object {
    Test-Connection $Server -Count 1 -Quiet
} | ForEach-Object {
    Convert-QueryToObjects $_ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-not $?) { $openservers += $_ }
} | Where-Object {
    $_.SessionState -eq 'Disconnected' -or
    ($_.SessionState -eq 'Active' -and
    [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.IdleTime, 'hh:mm', $culture) -gt $reftime)
} | ForEach-Object {
    Disconnect-LoggedOnUser -ComputerName $_.ComputerName -Id $_.ID -Verbose 
}

$openservers | Out-File 'H:\demo\session\openservers.txt'
```